# Rails/ActiveRecord - association not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, nested-attributes

I can't get my CheckIn record to save because the associated Tenancy isn't saving.

I have three models with associations:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tenancies
end

class Tenancy < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :check_ins
end

class CheckIn < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tenancy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tenancy
end
```

I want the CheckIn new action to create both the CheckIn and the associated Tenancy:

```
def new
  @check_in = CheckIn.new
  @check_in.build_tenancy.property_id = params[:property_id]
end
```

I have to include the property_id part otherwise the Tenancy won't save.

The form in check_ins/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @check_in, url: property_check_ins_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :date_time %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :date_time, {minute_step: 15} %>

  <%= f.label :tenancy %>
  <%= f.fields_for :tenancy do |i| %>
    <%= i.date_select :start_date %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Create Check In" %>
<% end %>
```

I've added tenancy attributes to the strong params in the CheckInsController:

```
def check_in_params
  params.require(:check_in).permit(:tenancy_id, :date_time, tenancy_attributes: [:start_date])
end
```

It's worth noting that the check_ins routes are nested in properties:

```
resources :properties do
  resources :check_ins, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

So the problem is that by the time I get to the create action in the CheckInsController, the tenancy that I built has disappeared. I'm not sure how and when each of the records should be being saved and the slight complexity of what I'm trying to achieve has made it quite difficult to find relevant help so any ideas?

I'm using Rails 5.

Comment: Have you added `tenancy_attributes` in strong_params

Comment: I have, I added that in to the original question, thanks

Comment: Ah, I did just realise that I don't have :tenancy_id in the permitted params.. but then I put it in and it still doesn't save

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the property attached to the tenancy was being forgotten. I removed the property attachment from the new action:

```
def new
  @check_in = CheckIn.new
  @check_in.build_tenancy
end
```

Added a hidden field for property_id to the form (as well as adding :property_id to the strong params):

```
<%= f.fields_for :tenancy do |i| %>
  <%= i.date_select :start_date %>
  <%= i.hidden_field :property_id, value: params[:property_id] %>
<% end %>
```

And saved the tenancy in the CheckIn create action, prior to saving the check in itself:

```
def create
  @check_in = CheckIn.new(check_in_params)
  @check_in.tenancy.save

  if @check_in.save
    redirect_to property_check_in_path(@check_in.tenancy.property.id, @check_in)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

I'd certainly be interested if anyone could pick holes in this solution or offer a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Using nested resources (check_ins depends from properties)  you create a namespaces routes. **form_for helper** ( [rails guides - form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) ) when you build your form, need a Property reference also.

I try to explain me better with an example:

**#checks_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @property = Property.new
  @check_in = @property.build_check_ins
  @check_in.build_tenancy
end
```

**#check_ins/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@property, @check_in], url: property_check_ins_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :date_time %>
  <%= f.datetime_select :date_time, {minute_step: 15} %>

  <%= f.label :tenancy %>
  <%= f.fields_for :tenancy do |i| %>
    <%= i.date_select :start_date %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Create Check In" %>
<% end %>
```

I haven't tried this code, but I hope this give you at least a way to follow to solve your problem.